# Keras model.evaluate and model.predict give different results

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I build a model using Lambda layer to calculate the sum along an axis, model.evaluate() gives different result in comparison to manually calculating from model.predict(). I have checked the output data types and shapes and it did not help. The problem only occurs when I use tensorflow as Keras backend. It works fine when I use CNTK as backend.

Here is a minimal code that can reproduce this behavior.

```py
from keras.layers import Input,Lambda
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model

import numpy as np
inp=Input((2,))
out=Lambda(lambda x:K.sum(x,axis=-1),output_shape=(1,))(inp)
model=Model(input=inp,output=out)
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer="sgd")
xs=np.random.random((3,2))
ys=np.sum(xs,axis=1)

print(np.mean((model.predict(xs)-ys)**2)) # This is zero
print(model.evaluate(xs,ys))  # This is not zero
```

I establish a network with no parameters and should simply calculate the sum for each x, and ys are constructed so that it should be the same with the output from the model. model.predict() gives the same results as ys, but model.evaluate() gives something non-zero when I use tensorflow as backend.

Any idea about why this should happen? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jerry, great question, I have a similar problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: At the time my solution was just to use CNTK as backend